# Cross-platform cooperative file locking through link/folder creation?

Tags: python, windows, unix, file-locking, filelock

I would like to implement a cooperative file locking mechanism in Python, that would also work on remote partitions (e.g. NFS), with a simple code (I want to avoid using a third-party module, because I want some specific open-source code to not have dependencies).

There are solutions out there that look relatively cross-platform, but they are [more complicated](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch04s25.html) than I would like: ideally the exact same lines of code would run on all platforms.

A solution is to use some **atomic operation** that tries to create a lock and fails if it cannot (e.g. a lock in the form of a directory). Creating a **directory** [is atomic on Unix](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex), so that's a good first step. Now, **what would be an equivalent solution for Windows**? I have read somewhere that maybe creating a link (how?) would be atomic; if [creating a directory is atomic on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986621/is-mkdir-still-atomic-windows-7-filesystems-mounted-on-san), that would be even better, as the same code could be used for both Windows and Unix, but I can't find out whether this is the case.

**To summarize**: what would be a **simple**, **cross-platform** Python **code** (no library) for creating (and releasing) a **cooperative file lock**, that also works on remote partitions? The directory creation route looks promising, but does it work on Windows?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but to the comment, still think people should be forced to comment / pick a reason when downvoting, I know folks on meta disagree with it, but it's just annoying when you take time to ask a well-prepared question like that and get it downvoted...

Comment: Agreed. Now, I a "close" flag (for a "too broad" question) was raised after my comment, so that may be the explanation for the downvote. :)

Comment: Before going down the rabbit hole of seeking atomic file-system functions, are you aware of [`msvcrt.locking`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.locking) for Windows?

Comment: I am, thanks. But again, I would prefer using the same code for all platforms, so that rules out the Windows-specific `msvcrt` module.